# Equivalent settings between WinSCP and FileZilla on Tunnel

Tags: ftp, sftp, scp, filezilla, winscp

I am running Ubuntu 14.04LTS and have FileZilla 3.7.3 installed, I also have a VM running WIN7 with WinSCP  5.5.1.

Under WIN7 when using WinSCP, in the editing dialog under the advanced tab there is a category “Connection” with two options, Proxy and Tunnel . The server I need to FTP or SFTP requires a tunnel, so my setting are Connection through ssh tunnel checked off as yes. The host name Tunnel.rr.net on port 22 and I have to enter in my user name and password, file protcall is set to SFTP, local tunnel port is set to Autoselect and no private key is needed. I know these setting are correct because it works just fine for me I my WIN7 VM, I select the server I need, I see it connect to the tunnel and than my server.

I am new to FileZillaile and the setting options seem to be a bit more extensive, the closest thing I see equivalent is under settings in Generic Proxy. So I set my tunnel host, user name and password which I know are correct because I have no issue with WinSCP.

When I set the Generic proxy to HTTP/1.1 using CONNECT method I get error, Error:   Proxy error: HTTP response was absent
 & Error:   Could not connect to server, when I set it to SOCK 5 I get an error Error:  Proxy error: SOCKS proxy returned unexpected version
 & Error:   Could not connect to server.

Again, I am new to FileZilla so it must be a setting that missing glaring because it is too simple under WinSCP.

So what would the equivalent of “tunnel” be on with WinSCP , in FileZilla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileZilla does not support anything equivalent to [WinSCP SSH tunneling feature](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel).

---

You can of course tunnel it through an external SSH tunnel. E.g. via PuTTY or OpenSSH `ssh`.

See my guide [Setting up tunnel using PuTTY for SFTP/SCP session](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel#tunnel_putty).
*(The guide is for WinSCP, but works for any SFTP/SCP client.)*

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to respond....

I am relatively a new Linux user, I can see why you need putty on a windows os but never realived it provides added value to Linux where SSH is supported at the command line. I have been doing some searching on the topic of SSH tunnels and FileZilla and I am having a hard time getting my head wrapped around this. So essentially I am establishing an SSH tunel through my local host and FileZilla connects to the local host?

Comment: Yes. Note that as you are on Unix, you do not need to use PuTTY, standard OpenSSH `ssh` can serve the same purpose.